# Kibana doesn't show results in Discover tab

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new to elastic stack and I try to run this example:
https://github.com/melvynator/ELK_twitter

The tweets are showing up in terminal when I run the config command, and the indexing in kibana also works well. However, after I do the last part of instructions about Setting up Kibana there are no results in discover tab or the dashboards

running the command >curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v | sort I get these results :
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPjpa.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure that you have Time Range set to proper range? It's at the top right corner, try changing it to for example a year.

Comment: Yes I tried  even the last 5 years and nothing

Comment: Run this command and show us what it returns: `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v | sort` also how do you define an index in Kibana?

Comment: I follow exactly the instructions in the readme file of the github example. If I have understand correct the index is created by the json files of the example.

Comment: Please also show us how do you setup a new index.